# Android audio input

Tags: audio, input-methods

I know that on the iPhone you can plug in your guitar and other audio devices but can you do this on Android? Can any recording application do this?

Comment: This question should not be tagged with "input-method", as it's about audio input and not text input.

Answer (score 3):

The headphone jack of many android devices will accept audio input.  A few caveats:

1. Audio input using this method is **mono only**.
2. This will vary by device as some may not accept audio input, and others simply don't have headphone jacks.  If a particular device came with a headset with a built-in mic, odds are it will accept audio input.
3. This method [does not support the use of an external mic while recording video](http://www.tested.com/news/androids-headphone-jack-is-versatile-yet-underused/522/).
4. You'll need to use a special adapter that will split the input/output of the jack.  Something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002SK66OY) or the adapter mentioned [here](http://www.tested.com/news/record-better-audio-with-the-iphones-audio-input-options/519/) would probably work.

It seems like audio input through USB would be possible, but this [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12430) suggests it isn't yet implemented.